# Calculate memory usage for all process. Display result in Gb

Tags: powershell

I have code below. How can I get the result in GB?

```
Get-Process | Measure-Object -Property PM -Sum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the result with built-in gigabyte constant. Before you can do that, remember to access the `.Sum` property of the result. Like so,

```
(Get-Process | Measure-Object -Property PM -Sum).sum/1gb
```

For nicer an output, consider rounding and formatting. Like so,

```
"{0} GB" -f [math]::round((Get-Process | Measure-Object -Property PM -Sum).sum/1gb, 2)
# Output
5,96 GB
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was easy :)